# Soda stream syrup vegetarian?

Tags: food, recipe-request, is-it-vegetarian

What soda stream syrups are vegetarian in nature? We have several at home & I figured that others that are considering getting one that a vegetarians might want to know as well! If they aren’t vegetarian could you direct me to some vegetarian recipes that would work with the soda steam? I would have put down a drink tag but there isn’t one to put down in the first place.

Comment: Vegetarian, or vegan? Are there particular indigents you are concerned about?

Comment: Vegetarian mostly & no particular ingredients that I’m concerned about.

Comment: Do you care about people in addition to animals? By supporting Soda Stream, you're supporting the genocide in occupied Palestine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SodaStream syrups are all vegetarian given that their primary ingredients are sweeteners. No meat or fish products are used in common commercialized syrups.

SodaStream has [confirmed](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813174707/https://support.sodastream.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009219153-Are-any-of-your-flavors-vegan-) that its Fruit Drops are 100% vegan, while most of their other syrups are "vegan-friendly."

If you are still unsure about the ingredients of a SodaStream syrup, consider trying a [homemade recipe](https://web.archive.org/web/20210923063329/http://www.sodasherpa.com/best-sodastream-recipes/). To keep your syrups vegan, make sure to avoid honey as a sweetener.